# Proper namespace naming for new sub-business unit

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces

We have the current structure:

- BusinessName.Common - common entities, classes, utilities
- BusinessName.Services - business services

We're adding a sub-unit called "Medical", of which it will contain a similar structure. I'm stuck deciding on the best naming convention.

Option 1

- BusinessName.Medical.Common
- BusinessName.Medical.Services

Option 2:

- BusinessName.Common.Medical
- BusinessName.Services.Medical

There will eventually be more sub-units such as this.

Comment: so what's the issue.. why not stick to the same naming convention
`BusinessName.Common` `BusinessName.Services` `BusinessName.Common.Medical` and BusinessName.Services.Medical` what is the issue.. are you familiar with how namespaces work..?

Comment: Uh, yes, I'm familiar with how they work... I'm adding a new unit and want input as to naming for the sub-unit.

Comment: If you are familiar then you kind of answered your own question.. basically it's your own opinion when doing namespacing.. what's the big issue..??

Comment: I'm asking if there are guidelines for naming.

Comment: read up on MSDN NameSpace I think that will answer your question I still don't see how this is an issue personally unless you are running into to some method collision some where and you are not fully qualifying your namespace when something like this could possibly happen

Comment: No issue. As I said. Just asking the community for guidelines. Christ...

Comment: This would almost boil down to Opinionated I would suggest trying something sticking with it and if you have issues then we can help guide you in regards to refactoring

Comment: no thanks this is not worth my time at the moment I am busy as well sorry

Comment: @DJKRAZE Keep calm, man!!!!!!!!! If you don't like a question, just skip it hahaha

Comment: it's not about like or dislike it's about `Opinionated` vs `What have you tried` I don't think OP truly understand how to use namespace

Answer (score 1):

I would stick with **Option 1**, because each domain should mimic the same child namespace naming scheme.

If you call `BusinessName.Common` a shared library across all domains (what you call units...), a specific domain common members are of the whole domain, thus, your naming scheme should be `BusinessName.[DomainName].Common`, `BusinessName.[DomainName].Services`.

Anyway, let me add more value to this answer. You said that `Common` project/namespace would contain *common entities, classes, utilities*. I'm not agree with this. A *common* library should be a cross-layer library (vertical). My advise is that you should organize your solution this way:

- `BusinessName.Common`: Infrastructure code. Any domain-related code shouldn't be here. Classes, interfaces and enumerations here should be usable from any layer and tier.
- `BusinessName.Domain`: Common domain entities and services. I would put here common domain interfaces, abstract classes, base classes...
- `BusinessName.Domain.[SomeDomain]`. For example `BusinessName.Domain.Medical`. I would put here everything about domain. In a specific domain there're no common entities to any other domain, because this would defeat the purpose of organizing your project in domains.

In my own projects I prefer to use `Shared` identifier instead of `Common`, but this is just my opinion.